iPadOS: Notifying users when driver extension is loaded and application is not running
Currently, I am developing an iPadOS app that comes bundled with a Driverkit based extension for managing USB devices. This extension runs in the background, matching against a specific set of USB devices when connected and users can enable/disable it from the app settings. It is possible to guide users to the app settings screen or push local notifications when the app is running or in the background. However, I could not come up with a way to do the same whenever the app is not running or is force-quit by the user. I have explored for solutions but all of them have the app either open or running in the background.
As the driver becomes active whenever a device is connected, is it possible to notify from the driver extension in some way? If not, can I notify the user in some other way?
